# Why dryers or oven have a neutral if 240V circuits do not require neutral?

Tags: electrical, 240v

I am looking at two different circuits for 1) an oven and 2) a radiant heat system. Both 240V. The oven circuit requires a neutral, while radiant heat circuit does not.

Why oven or dryer circuit have a neutral if a 240V circuits does not require neutral?

Comment: Some appliances have internal loads which do require 120V - for instance a dryer has the motor and controls same as a gas fired dryer which uses a 120V socket, and an oven needs 120V for the oven light so you can use "standard" incandescent bulbs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The oven circuit is technically a 240/120V since it provides both 240V and 120V depending on which two pins you use.  See this lovely diagram (created for a 50A RV receptacle, but the theory is the same.)

Since you have L1, L2, *and* neutral, you can access 120V, 240V, or both.

[image]

The reasoning behind it is because the oven contains electronics that utilize the 120V, while the heating elements use the 240V.  That keeps the appliance manufacturers from having to make different brains for gas ranges, since they might not have access to 240V.

Radiant electric heaters commonly do not have any parts that need the 120V so they can use straight 240V.  If they have controls, they are commonly line-voltage (240V) or low-voltage (24V).

Answer (score 0):

Neutral usually needed for lights, receptacles, controls.

The hot stuff usually does not need neutral.

Most of it could all done with no neutral, except for 120v receptacles, so it is mostly a design matter and cost.